# FailedPreconditionError: sequence_length(0) <= X

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using TensorFlow to implement a convolutional recurrent neural network as described by this paper: [Arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.05717).

All my code is available here: [crnn](https://github.com/Belval/crnn)

So I am loading X number of training samples of various length. When loading the training set I resize them to 32x2000. When putting them through the neural net, TensorFlow throws this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: sequence_length(0) <= 124
 [[Node: CTCBeamSearchDecoder = CTCBeamSearchDecoder[beam_width=100, merge_repeated=true, top_paths=1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](transpose/_3, _recv_seq_len_0)]]
 [[Node: CTCLoss/_5 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_758_CTCLoss", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

Strangely, I do not get a lot of results on Google so I thought it was worth asking about.

It is worth noting that I do not have 124 anywhere in my code nor in my data so I am quite baffled.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests that you have some malformed examples in your training data. By this, I mean examples where you have too few labels for some image. Try to check for empty or abnormally short labels.

The 124 comes from the `max_pool` operations in the convolutional part and the number represents the length of the final feature vector. If you have four `max_pools` of stride `2` on the width, then the image width will be reduced by a factor of `2**4 = 16` => For an input image `32 x 2000`, the final feature map size is `1 x 125 x F` (F is the number of filters). Not sure why `124` and not `125`, probably some bug or uses an index instead of `len`.